# Can the ConfigurationAPI in Liferay DXP be used for Plugin sdk portlet?

Tags: configuration, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

I have followed given 2 tutorials to use COnfigurationAPI in a Liferay dxp plugins SDK portlet built using Ant/Ivy.
[COnfiguration API 1](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/transitioning-from-portlet-preferences-to-the-configuration-api)
[COnfiguration API 2](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/making-your-applications-configurable).

Below is the configuration class used:

```
package com.preferences.interfaces;

import com.liferay.portal.configuration.metatype.annotations.ExtendedObjectClassDefinition;

import aQute.bnd.annotation.metatype.Meta;

@ExtendedObjectClassDefinition(
    category = "preferences",
    scope = ExtendedObjectClassDefinition.Scope.GROUP
)
@Meta.OCD(
    id = "com.preferences.interfaces.UnsupportedBrowserGroupServiceConfiguration",
    name = "UnsupportedBrowser.group.service.configuration.name"
)
public interface UnsupportedBrowserGroupServiceConfiguration {

    @Meta.AD(deflt = "", required = false)
    public String displayStyle();

    @Meta.AD(deflt = "0", required = false)
    public long displayStyleGroupId(long defaultDisplayStyleGroupId);

}
```

Post following the steps,I am getting the below error:

> ERROR [CM Configuration Updater (ManagedService Update: pid=[com.preferences.interfaces.UnsupportedBrowserGroupServiceConfiguration])][org_apache_felix_configadmin:97] [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService, id=7082, bundle=297//com.liferay.portal.configuration.settings-2.0.15.jar?lpkgPath=C:\dev\Liferay\osgi\marketplace\Liferay Foundation.lpkg]: Unexpected problem updating configuration com.preferences.interfaces.UnsupportedBrowserGroupServiceConfiguration {org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin}={service.vendor=Apache Software Foundation, service.pid=org.apache.felix.cm.ConfigurationAdmin, service.description=Configuration Admin Service Specification 1.2 Implementation, service.id=56, service.bundleid=643, service.scope=bundle}
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

So,does this process need a osgi module as mandatory or can we do it using plusings sdk portlet built using ant as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without disecting the error message `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`:

The way you build your plugin (Ant, Maven, Gradle, manually) doesn't make a difference, as long as you build a plugin that will be understood by the runtime. `aQute.bnd.annotation.metatype.Meta` points firmly into the OSGi world, and makes it almost certain that you'll need an OSGi module. You can build this with Ant, of course. Even in Ant you can embed tools like bnd, or you can write the proper Manifest.mf to include in your module manually (just kidding - you don't want to do it manually, but it would work).

Recommendation: Instead of moving everything over: Try to reproduce this with a minimal example in gradle or better Liferay Workspace (which is gradle based), just to get all the automatic wiring in. Check if it makes a difference and compare the generated output from your Ant build process with the workspace output. Pay specific attention to the Manifest.

In order to build the proper Manifest, you want to use bnd - if the Manifest turns out to be your issue: Find a way to embrace bnd - if that's by saying goodby to Ant, or by tweaking your build script remains your decision.